# how to apply a groupby on list of tuples in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, group-by, tuples

In my function I will create different tuples and add to an empty list :

```
tup = (pattern,matchedsen)
matchedtuples.append(tup)
```

The patterns have format of regular expressions. I am looking for apply `groupby()` on `matchedtuples` in following way:

For example :

```
matchedtuples = [(p1, s1) , (p1,s2) , (p2, s5)]
```

And I am looking for this result:

```
result = [ (p1,(s1,s2)) , (p2, s5)]
```

So, in this way I will have groups of sentences with the same pattern. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

My answer for your question will work for any input structure you will use and print the same output as you gave. And i will use only `groupby` from `itertools` module:

```
# Let's suppose your input is something like this
a = [("p1", "s1"), ("p1", "s2"), ("p2", "s5")]

from itertools import groupby

result = []

for key, values in groupby(a, lambda x : x[0]):
    b = tuple(values)
    if len(b) >= 2:
        result.append((key, tuple(j[1] for j in b)))
    else:
        result.append(tuple(j for j in b)[0])

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('p1', ('s1', 's2')), ('p2', 's5')]
```

The same solution work if you add more values to your input:

```
# When you add more values to your input
a = [("p1", "s1"), ("p1", "s2"), ("p2", "s5"), ("p2", "s6"), ("p3", "s7")]

from itertools import groupby

result = []

for key, values in groupby(a, lambda x : x[0]):
    b = tuple(values)
    if len(b) >= 2:
        result.append((key, tuple(j[1] for j in b)))
    else:
        result.append(tuple(j for j in b)[0])

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('p1', ('s1', 's2')), ('p2', ('s5', 's6')), ('p3', 's7')]
```

Now, if you modify your input structure:

```
# Let's suppose your modified input is something like this
a = [(["p1"], ["s1"]), (["p1"], ["s2"]), (["p2"], ["s5"])]

from itertools import groupby

result = []

for key, values in groupby(a, lambda x : x[0]):
    b = tuple(values)
    if len(b) >= 2:
        result.append((key, tuple(j[1] for j in b)))
    else:
        result.append(tuple(j for j in b)[0])

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[(['p1'], (['s1'], ['s2'])), (['p2'], ['s5'])]
```

Also, the same solution work if you add more values to your new input structure:

```
# When you add more values to your new input
a = [(["p1"], ["s1"]), (["p1"], ["s2"]), (["p2"], ["s5"]), (["p2"], ["s6"]), (["p3"], ["s7"])]

from itertools import groupby

result = []

for key, values in groupby(a, lambda x : x[0]):
    b = tuple(values)
    if len(b) >= 2:
        result.append((key, tuple(j[1] for j in b)))
    else:
        result.append(tuple(j for j in b)[0])

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[(['p1'], (['s1'], ['s2'])), (['p2'], (['s5'], ['s6'])), (['p3'], ['s7'])]
```

**Ps:** Test this code and if it breaks with any other kind of inputs please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you require the output you present, you'll need to manually loop through the grouping of `matchedtuples` and build your list.

First, of course, if the `matchedtuples` list isn't sorted, sort it with `itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter as itmg

li = sorted(matchedtuples, key=itmg(0))
```

Then, loop through the result supplied by `groupby` and append to the list `r` based on the size of the group:

```
r = []
for i, j in groupby(matchedtuples, key=itmg(0)):
    j = list(j)
    ap = (i, j[0][1]) if len(j) == 1 else (i, tuple(s[1] for s in j))
    r.append(ap)
```